# a consumer consumes the same message many times - masstransit

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-sqs, masstransit

there are 2 apps which are work as consumers and producers.
app1 and app2. both of them are asp.net core web **api**.

app1 or app2 publish a message and both app1 and app2 consume the message.
but sometimes app1 consumes the same message many times ( from 2 to 478) but the same message is consuming by app2 just one time as expected. the consume method is very simple just one select and one insert operation.

at first, I thought after insert operation some exceptions occurred so masstransit enqueued it and tried to consume it again. but there is no code to make exceptions after insert operation. even if there is, we send exceptions to the sentry but there is nothing about exception in sentry.

according to **aws** **sqs** logs there are abnormal message counts in a specific period of time

[image]

app2's queue is normal

there are my configurations and codes below. so what could cause this?

**configurations**
[image]

### app1

masstransit configuration

```
public static IServiceCollection AddEventBus(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddTransient<OrderCompletedIntegrationEvent>();

    var options = configuration.GetSection("AmazonSqs").Get<AmazonSqsOptions>();
    var massOptions = configuration.GetSection("Masstransit").Get<MasstransitOptions>();
    IBusControl CreateBus(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var secretManagerService = serviceProvider.GetService<ISecretManagerService>();
        var secrets = secretManagerService.GetSecrets();
        var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAmazonSqs(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Host(options.Region, h =>
            {
                h.AccessKey(secrets.AccessKeyId);
                h.SecretKey(secrets.SecretKey);
            });
            cfg.Durable = true;
            cfg.WaitTimeSeconds = 10;
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(options.QueueName, q =>
            {
                // RetryCount: 1
                // RetryWaitIntervalInSeconds: 1
                q.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(massOptions.RetryCount, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(massOptions.RetryWaitIntervalInSeconds)));
                q.ConfigureConsumer<OrderCompletedIntegrationEventHandler>(serviceProvider);

            });
        });                

        return bus;
    }

    // local function to configure consumers
    void ConfigureMassTransit(IServiceCollectionConfigurator configurator)
    {
        configurator.AddConsumer<OrderCompletedIntegrationEventHandler>();
    }

    // configures MassTransit to integrate with the built-in dependency injection
    services.AddMassTransit(configurator =>
    {
        configurator.AddBus(CreateBus);
        ConfigureMassTransit(configurator);
    });
    services.AddMassTransitHostedService();


    return services;
}
```

consumer

```
public class OrderCompletedIntegrationEventHandler : IConsumer<OrderCompletedIntegrationEvent>
{
    private readonly MasstransitOptions options;
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
    private readonly ICoinService coinService;
    private readonly IAccountService accountService;
    private readonly ILogger<OrderCompletedIntegrationEventHandler> _logger;

    public OrderCompletedIntegrationEventHandler(
        IConfiguration configuration,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        ICoinService coinService,
        IAccountService accountService)
    {
        options = configuration.GetSection("Masstransit").Get<MasstransitOptions>();
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        this.coinService = coinService;
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<OrderCompletedIntegrationEvent> context)
    {
        var @event = context.Message;
        var retry = context.GetRetryAttempt();
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var coin = coinService.TlToCoin(@event.Total);
                var coinToAdd = coin * 25 / 1000;
                var user = accountService.FindByEmail(@event.Email);
                if (user != null) coinService.AddBonus(user.Id, coinToAdd);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (retry == options.RetryCount)
            {
                using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                {
                    var hub = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IHub>();
                    hub.CaptureException(new IntegrationEventException(data: @event, ex));
                }
            }
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

### app2

masstransit configuration

```
public static IServiceCollection AddEventBus(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddScoped<OrderCompletedIntegrationEventHandler>();

    var options = configuration.GetSection("AmazonSqs").Get<AmazonSqsOptions>();
    var massOptions = configuration.GetSection("Masstransit").Get<MasstransitOptions>();

    IBusControl CreateBus(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAmazonSqs(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.UseAmazonSqsMessageScheduler();

            cfg.Host(options.Region, h =>
            {
                h.AccessKey(options.AccessKeyId);
                h.SecretKey(options.SecretKey);
            });

            cfg.Durable = true;
            cfg.WaitTimeSeconds = 20;

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(options.QueueName, q =>
            {
                // RetryCount: 5
                // RetryWaitIntervalInSeconds: 300
                q.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(massOptions.RetryCount, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(massOptions.RetryWaitIntervalInSeconds)));
                q.ConfigureConsumer<OrderCompletedIntegrationEventHandler>(serviceProvider);
            });
        });
    }

    // local function to configure consumers
    void ConfigureMassTransit(IServiceCollectionConfigurator configurator)
    {
        configurator.AddConsumer<OrderCompletedIntegrationEventHandler>();
    }

    //configures MassTransit to integrate with the built -in dependency injection
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.AddBus(CreateBus);
        ConfigureMassTransit(x);
    });
    services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

    return services;
}
```

consumer

```
public class OrderCompletedIntegrationEventHandler : IConsumer<OrderCompletedIntegrationEvent>
{
    private readonly MasstransitOptions options;
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
    private IUserService _userService;
    private IScoreService _scoreService;
    public OrderCompletedIntegrationEventHandler(
        IConfiguration configuration,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IUserService userService, IScoreService scoreService)
    {
        options = configuration.GetSection("Masstransit").Get<MasstransitOptions>();
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        this._userService = userService;
        this._scoreService = scoreService;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<OrderCompletedIntegrationEvent> context)
    {
        var @event = context.Message;
        var retry = context.GetRetryAttempt();
        try
        {
            var user = _userService.GetUserByEmail(@event.Email);
            if (user != null)
            {

                var activity = _scoreService.GetActivityTypeByName("buy-book");
                var scoreToAdd = Convert.ToInt32(@event.Total * 150);
                var coinToAdd = Convert.ToInt32(@event.Total * 100 * 2.5M / 100);
                var scoreModel = new ScoreModel
                {
                    ActivityType = new ActivityType
                    {
                        Id = activity.Id
                    },
                    Name = activity.Name,
                    Description = $"{@event.Total:F2} TL'lik bir sipariş verildi. Sipariş no: {@event.OrderId}",
                    UserId = (int)user.ID,
                    BranchId = null,
                    GainedScore = scoreToAdd,
                    GainedCoins = coinToAdd,
                    CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow.TurkeyTime()
                };
                await _scoreService.AddActivity(scoreModel);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            if (retry == options.RetryCount)
            {
                using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                {
                    var hub = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IHub>();
                    hub.CaptureException(ex);
                }
            }

            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As exceptions are handled by MassTransit as part of the exception handling with retries, you won't see an exception thrown on the outside unless the retry count exceeds. I am not sure what `IHub` is but you also send the exception there only when the retry count is exceeded, so all the exceptions happened before that will not be show anywhere except the logs if you configure the logger factory and enable warnings.

Comment: thanks alexey, IHub is a service that we send exceptions to sentry (error tracking service) manually. 
actually, you're right but our retry count is 1. we send exceptions to sentry after just 1 retry. but messages sometimes consumed hundreds of times.

Comment: Configure logging so that you can view the detailed MassTransit message processing, and you'll see any hidden errors/exceptions, and if you enable debug logging you'll see every message as it is delivered from the transport.

Comment: Also, is this an old existing app or a new app? MassTransit v6 is really old, and no longer officially supported.

Comment: thanks @ChrisPatterson ,
i did try to log it, but i couldn't reproduce the case. i published thousands of messages but it worked so proper.  but if i couldn't find the answer i'll configure logging in production as you say and wait for some clues. or i'll just upgrade the masstransit :)

Comment: it's 2-3 years old app. we used version 6.2.5 since v6.2.5 was released. i'll upgrade asap, thanks.

can i ask you in what conditions messages requeued or how the masstransit convinced that messages were successfully consumed?

Comment: and there is one more thing, it may help us. the time between consumings of the same message is 30 seconds.